# How can i target multiple functions in Python using Thread

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to target one more function of let say odd number using the same thread
Here is my code.

```
from threading import *

def evenNumber():
print(current_thread().getName())
for x in range(10):
    if x%2==0:
        print(x," ")
#print(current_thread().getName())
t= Thread(target=evenNumber)
t.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
def even_odd():
    evenNumber()
    oddNumber()

t= Thread(target=even_odd)
t.start()
```

Comment: Thanks...but is there no way to target multiple function in the constructor method of Thread

Comment: @BilalKhan as far as I know, no. The [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread) say that target has to be a callable object